# How to get all the values from a list that are smaller or equivalent to another list in python

Tags: python

I have two lists:

```
List1 = [1,5,9,15,17,23]
List2=[1,2,3,8,15,20,29,27,34,38,39,56]
```

I want to compare List1 and List2 and want to get all the values from List1 and also those values in List2 which are either smaller or equivalent to any values in List1.

so my resultant list will be
[1,5,9,15,17,23,1,2,3,8,15,20]

Comment: What was your approach for the solution?

Comment: What do you mean by compare? It looks like all you are doing is concatenating list2 to list1 where the values in list2 <= max(list1).

Comment: @SayanChowdhury I thought of using nested loop. But that is not the path I wanted to go

Comment: @AChampion: u can say so. I just need the values from list2 which are smaller or same as the values of list1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l1  = [1,5,9,15,17,23]
l2 = [1,2,3,8,15,20,29,27,34,38,39,56]

max_val = max(l1)

l1 + [val for val in l2 if val <= max_val]
```

Comment: `l1 + [val for val in l2 if val <= max_val]` would also work and avoid comparing list1 with its maximum.

Comment: @AChampion - good point. I put the answer up sort of reflexively, without any thought. Edited the answer to use your variant.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
max1 = max(List1)
max2 = max(List2)
newlist = [x for x in List1 if x <= max2] + [x for x in List2 if x <= max1]
```

You could put the max call into the list comprehension, but that would be slower.  (They would need to be evaluated once for each item in List1 and List2 instead of just once.)

Answer (score 1):

This concatenates List1 and every element val of List2 which is greater than max element of List1 and stores in List3.

```
List1 = [1,5,9,15,17,23]
List2 = [1,2,3,8,15,20,29,27,34,38,39,56]

List3 = List1 + [val for val in List2 if val <= max(List1)]
```

Comment: "either smaller _or equivalent_ to any values in List1"

Comment: Corrected it just now.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is a better alternative:

```
max1 = max(List1)
result = List1[:]

for x in List2:
    if x <= max1:
        if not x in result:
            result.append(x)
```

If you don't need to worry about changing List1 you could use it instead of making a copy of it's items. Also, if you allow duplicates, you could get rid of the x in if.

Comment: 1. It's probably going to be significantly slower than a list comprehension variant. 2. It doesn't give the correct answer

Comment: As I said in my comment, you could allow duplicates by removing the if that checks x in result. The different behavior was intended as an alternate solution, removing the duplicates. But yes, after changing the code to allow duplicates, my implementation will be approximately 2 seconds slower after running both solutions 1MM times.